# NSIS Registry Plugin not found

Tags: registry, nsis

When compiling an NSIS script, whenever I invoke registry (or time) macros contained in the Registry.nsh and Time.nsh plugins, I get an error.

The command I run is something like:

```
${registry::Open} "[fullpath]" "[Options]" $var
```

And the error I get is:

```
Plugin not found, cannot call registry::_Open
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Edit: Using NSIS 3.0b2

Comment: I believe that message was added in a recent NSIS Beta version, in the future it would be nice if you specified the version of the compiler you are using...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the plugin .dll in the correct subdirectory. For NSIS v2.x this is in `...\NSIS\Plugins` and for NSIS v3.x it is `...\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi` for ANSI plugins and `...\NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode` for Unicode plugins.

You can also store plugins in other folders and use `!addplugindir` if you have [multiple NSIS installations](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_can_I_install_a_plugin%3F#Multiple_NSIS_installations)...